# Seam Interceptor abstract base class

Tags: java, seam

i'm experimenting with seam interceptors.
I i have a custom annotation defined as:

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Interceptors(SomeInterceptor.class)
public @interface MyInterceptAnnotation { }
```

and i have a superclass annotated with @MyInterceptAnnotation

```
@MyInterceptAnnotation
MyAbstractSuperClass{...}
```

is possible to have all subclasses derived from MyAbstractSuperClass intercepted??
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I suppose. You can try that out. However, something can be done on `package` level, using `package-info.java`. So, the classes belong to that particular package will get intercepted. Like below,

*package-info.java*

```
@MyInterceptAnnotation
package my.package.name;
import my.annotation.package.name.MyInterceptAnnotation;
```

In order to force subclasses to define the annotation, look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95389/how-do-i-force-a-java-subclass-to-define-an-annotation).

Just came across a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380679/resource-annotation-not-injecting-a-subclass), but its about `Spring`. I wonder if we have similar way in `Seam`. You can try to find out.

Comment: How can i enable package-info level scanning?

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate your MyInterceptAnnotation with @Inherited which results all subclasses of MyAbstractSuperClass get intercepted too.